# Is there a way to properly display # of Office 365 licenses in Azure AD?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

Essentially what I am trying to do is store the values of a few particular properties from an object. The goal is to store the values of 'Enabled' and 'ConsumedUnits' into each of their own variables so that I may may show the difference or in other words the proper number of available licenses. This is preferred rather than having to manually subtract the number of 'ConsumedUnits' from 'Enabled' each time. I would like to then use those variables to calculate and display the number of available licenses for each one that meets the 'SkuPartNumber' criteria in my statement. Basically I would like to either display the amount of licenses available or throw an error if there are no licenses left to assign.

I would really like to append this portion to my new AD user on-boarding script for my employer to reduce the time it takes to create a user and assign licenses, groups, populate AD profile, etc.

Hopefully I've explained what I am trying to accomplish. I'm relatively new to Powershell and still trying to understand the syntax.

```
function Add-ADLicense
{
$Licenses =  Get-AzureADSubscribedSku | Select-Object -Property SkuPartNumber, 
             ConsumedUnits -ExpandProperty PrepaidUnits | Where-Object {($_.SkuPartNumber 
             -eq 'ENTERPRISEPACK' -or $_.SkuPartNumber -eq 'AAD_PREMIUM')} | Select-Obect 
             -Property SkuPartNumber, Enabled, ConsumedUnits

foreach($License in $Licenses)
{
    if ($_.SkuPartNumber -eq 'ENTERPRISEPACK')
    {
        $LicenseTotal = $_.Enabled
        $LicensesUsed = $_.ConsumedUnits
    }

    $AvailLicenses = $LicenseTotal - $LicensesUsed
    Write-Output $AvailLicenses
}
```

}